# Usage of State in functional component of React

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-state

How to use State in functional component of React ?

I have a component like below

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [count] = React.useState(0);    //Set State here

  function count_checkbox() {
    var applicable = [];
    const cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[class*="checkbox_value"]');
    cbs.forEach((cb) => {
      if (cb.checked) {
        applicable.push(parseInt(cb.value));
      }
    });
    this.setState({ count: applicable.length })  //Update State here
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="{ this.state.count }"/>   //Use State here
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But State is not working here.

Comment: [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional component is just a plain javascript function which takes props as an argument and returns a react element.
A stateless component has no state, it means that you can’t reach `this.state` and `this.setState()` inside it. It also has no lifecycle so you can’t use componentDidMount and other hooks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);    //Set initial state here

  function count_checkbox() {
    var applicable = [];
    const cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[class*="checkbox_value"]');
    cbs.forEach((cb) => {
      if (cb.checked) {
        applicable.push(parseInt(cb.value));
      }
    });
    setCount(applicable.length) //Update State here
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="submit" value={`Apply tax to  ${ count }  item(s)`} />   //You Can't use this.state.count here
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks @Etsuko Susui. How can I set initial value for `count` ?

Comment: ``const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);`` you can set initial value to 0

Comment: Thanks @Etsuko Susui. ` <input type="submit" id="button" value="{count}"/>` This portion is not working.

Comment: I wonder if input[submit] has value prop. I saw that as input[text].

Comment: Thanks @Etsuko Susui. 

I am trying to use this code `function count_checkbox() {
    var applicable = [];
    const cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[class="checkbox_value"]');
    cbs.forEach((cb) => {
      if (cb.checked) {
        applicable.push(parseInt(cb.value));
      }
    });
    setCount(applicable.length)
    alert(count);
  }`

I am getting previous value not current value. why ?

Comment: Try like this.  ``setCount(applicable.length, () => { alert(count);})``;  Please refer to this　https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Thanks @Etsuko Susui. How can I print this ? `<input type="submit" value='Apply tax to'  ${ count }  'item(s)' />`

Comment: You can do like this. <input type="submit" value=`Apply tax to  ${ count }  item(s)` />

Comment: I edited my answer because it is difficult to show code in comment.

Comment: Thanks @Etsuko Susui. Your solution is not working. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJDv4.png

Answer (score 2):

states should be like this

```
const [count,setCount] = React.useState(0); //setState

function count_checkbox() {
    var applicable = [];
    const cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[class*="checkbox_value"]');
    cbs.forEach((cb) => {
      if (cb.checked) {
        applicable.push(parseInt(cb.value));
      }
    });
    setCount(applicable.length)  //Update State here
  }
```

setCount sets the state count.

Comment: Thanks @Thennarasu Ramasamy. I am trying to use this code `function count_checkbox() {
    var applicable = [];
    const cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[class="checkbox_value"]');
    cbs.forEach((cb) => {
      if (cb.checked) {
        applicable.push(parseInt(cb.value));
      }
    });
    setCount(applicable.length)
    alert(count);
  }`

I am getting previous value not current value. why ?

Answer (score 2):

Updating the state in a functional component is different from a class component. The `useState` hook returns an array consisting of the value and a setter.

You then call the setter function to update the value of the state.

```
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

function count_checkbox() {
  ...
  setCount(applicable.length)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @koralarts. I am trying to use this code `function count_checkbox() {
    var applicable = [];
    const cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[class="checkbox_value"]');
    cbs.forEach((cb) => {
      if (cb.checked) {
        applicable.push(parseInt(cb.value));
      }
    });
    setCount(applicable.length)
    alert(count);
  }`

I am getting previous value not current value. why ?

Answer (score 2):

`this.setState` is unsed to update state in class components. In order to update state in functional component you need to update it with appropriate function.

useState returns 2 values first is current state value and second one function to update that state

```
 const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
```

Whenever you want to update `count` state you need to update with `setCount` function

```
  function count_checkbox() {
    ...
    setCount(applicable.length); //Update State here
  }
```

You can access `count` in your [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) like below:-

```
useEffect(() => {
  alert(count);
}, [count])
```

Comment: Thanks @Priyank Kachhela. I am trying to use this code `function count_checkbox() {
    var applicable = [];
    const cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[class="checkbox_value"]');
    cbs.forEach((cb) => {
      if (cb.checked) {
        applicable.push(parseInt(cb.value));
      }
    });
    setCount(applicable.length)
    alert(count);
  }`

I am getting previous value not current value. why ?

Comment: `setCount` is asynchronous so it will not reflect immediately in alert so you need to use useEffect in order to check correct value.

Comment: Thanks @Priyank Kachhela. How can I use `useEffect` ? I am new in React.

Comment: I have updated my answer, for more info refer this document: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html